# How can we compute the VC dimension of a finite class of sets?

Tags: ds.algorithms, co.combinatorics, vc-dimension

Let $F$ be a class of subsets of a finite set $X$ of cardinality $n$. What is the complexity of computing the VC dimension of $F$? Can we do better than looping through every subset of $X$ and checking if $F$ shatters it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In 1996 Papadimitriou and Yannakakis [noted](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000096900586?via%3Dihub) that there exists an $n^{O(\log n)}$ brute-force algorithm (where $n$ is the size of the input) for computing VC-dimension of a 0-1 matrix by checking all the subsets of size up to the trivial bound, the logarithm of the number of hypotheses.

Manurangsi and Rubinstein later [showed](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v65/manurangsi17a/manurangsi17a.pdf) this bound basically cannot be improved assuming the Exponential Time Hypothesis.  So, there is a brute-force quasi-polynomial time approach, but we don't expect to be able to improve it to get a polynomial-time algorithm.

Comment: I'm a noob so I could be wrong, but didn't the PY1996 paper just *note* there's an $n^{O(\log n)}$ algorithm, since one only needs to check if subsets of size at most $\lceil \log_2 n \rceil$ are shattered?

Comment: Is the $n$ in your answer the cardinality of what I call $X$, or the cardinality of what I call $F$?

Comment: @mathworker21 thanks you are right. I rephrased the answer to be clearer.

Comment: @JackM here $n$ is the size of the input, which I take to be the number of entries in the input matrix.